# Rails google maps api: InvalidValueError: setMap: not an instance of Map

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, heatmap

I use rails 4.2 and I try to show heatmap according to my datas. I can shown only map, for heatmaps give me `InvalidValueError: setMap: not an instance of Map` that error. So heatmap doesnt work, only can see the default map. 
my javascript codes is like below

```
:javascript
  var map;
  function initialize() {
     var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 10,
        center: {lat: latitude, lng: longitude},
        mapTypeId: 'satellite'
     };
     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
         mapOptions);
   };

  $( document ).ready(function() {
     initialize();
     function initMap() {
        var adrs = #{addresses.map{ |address| address[:address_set].select{ |a| a.latitude.present? && a.longitude.present? }.map{ |a| [a.latitude, a.longitude] }.uniq}};
        var gradients = [
      [
      'rgba(255, 0, 255, 0)',
      'rgba(255, 0, 255, 1)',
      'rgba(225, 0, 245, 1)',
      'rgba(205, 0, 235, 1)',
      'rgba(185, 0, 225, 1)',
      'rgba(165, 0, 215, 1)',
      'rgba(145, 0, 205, 1)',
      'rgba(125, 0, 195, 1)',
      'rgba(105, 0, 185, 1)',
      'rgba(85, 0, 175, 1)',
      'rgba(65, 0, 165, 1)',
      'rgba(45, 0, 155, 1)',
      'rgba(25, 0, 145, 1)',
      'rgba(0, 0, 135, 1)'
      ]
    ];

  function getPoints(points) {
    var gcs = [];
    points.forEach(function(value) {
      gcs.push(new google.maps.LatLng(value[0], value[1]));
    });
    return gcs;
  };

  heatmaps = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < adrs.length; i++) {
    heatmaps[i] = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
      data: getPoints(adrs[i]),
      gradient: gradients[i],
      radius: 10,
      opacity: 0.5,
      maxIntensity: 8,
      map: map
    });
  };
}
function toggleHeatmap() {
  for(var i = 0; i < heatmaps.length; i++) {
    heatmaps[i].setMap(map);
  };
}

 initMap();
 $('.change').on('click',function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   toggleHeatmap();
  });
});
```

All datas getting well, but the error still shown. How can I fix it ? 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: so set a breakpoint at `heatmaps[i].setMap(map);` and show us `heatmaps[i]`

Comment: Thank you for your opinion @FabrizioBertoglio I try to look at `heatmaps[i]` return `[object Object]`

Comment: then check `heatmaps` and specific that line `i`

Comment: `heatmaps` also return `[object Object]` and for `i` also return count of course according to loop

Comment: I found error thank you for your help @FabrizioBertoglio ! The error is that, I duplicated two times to API . so realize that thanks to Postman.